# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

I've tried writing this code in so many different ways but it returns this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createRecord' of undefined

```
App.StackFormComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    init: function() {
        this.set('stack', Ember.Object.create());
    },

    actions: {
        submit: function() {

            var newStack = this.store.createRecord('stack', {
                title: this.get('stack.title'),
                location: this.get('stack.location'),
                date: new Date().getTime(),
                details: this.get('stack.details'),
            });

            newStack.save();
        },

        cancel: function() {
            this.sendAction('cancel');
        }
    }
});


App.Stack = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    location: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('number'),
    details: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Unfortunately the answers from similar questions did not help. Any idea?

Comment: ``this.store`` is undefined, I can't see where you define ``store``?

Comment: I didn't know I had to define store. What is usually done? @BettySt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember injects `store` into Routes and Controllers, but not components, so that is your problem.

You can go ahead and inject the `store` into your component inside initializer as follows:

```
Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {
  Application.initializer({
    name: "injectStoreIntoMyComponent",
    after: "store",
    initialize: function(container, application) {      
      application.inject('component:good-test-comp', 'store', 'store:main');
    }
  });
});
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ralobu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. For some reason this didn't work on my amber app. So I ended up getting rid of the form component and put everything into the controller.

Comment: Putting everything in the controller would work just fine since `store` **is** injected into controllers automatically by ember like my answer says

Comment: Components will be taking over for controllers as we move to 2.0 – so it seems like you should stay in that direction. I'd be interested in an explanation of the code above. I have a form to post an event, and that should be a reusable component for various places etc. – In a CLI world - where would this go etc?

Comment: This is beautiful and perfect and saves me such a large headache, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Inject store into components is not a good design. You can pass it as an argument `{{my-component store=store}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting store in component is not good design. Instead we need to data to components and send action to communicate with data. If you still want to include it as special case then you can simply say,

```
store: Ember.inject.service()
```